# C++ Header files (basics)

Tags: c++, header, codeblocks

I was trying to use header files and source files but ran into issues. I therefore made a simplified version of what I am trying to do and I am getting the same error in CodeBlocks (undefined reference to `add(double, double)` in `main.cpp`).

In `add.cpp`:

```
double add (double x, double y)
{
    return x+y;
}
```

in `add.h`:

```
#ifndef ADD_H_INCLUDED
#define ADD_H_INCLUDED

double add(double, double);

#endif
```

in `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "add.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout<<add(3,4)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Note that when I add `#include "add.cpp"` to `add.h` everything works fine. But according to the textbook I'm following, this shouldn't be needed.

Comment: Is the add.cpp file part of your C::B project?

Comment: What is the file structure? Are all files in the same directory?

Comment: @wilx your reply and g.tsh's reply led me to the solution, the files were in the same directory and part of the project, but I just realized they aren't built by default, so I had to add them manually to the build targets (I'm starting out and these details aren't specified in textbooks) Thanks!

Comment: @g.tsh read my other comment :)

Comment: @Control Please write an answer how you solved your question, instead of marking Solved in the title and edit the solution in your question text.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i just did thanks for the heads up, first time using stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to manually specify the files as build targets as they are not built by default. In CodeBlocks this is done by right-clicking the project, going to properties > Build Targets and checking all the files in Debug and Release.